# Give access to Archive button in Launchpad

Tags: security, launchpad

I'm trying to add a button to the Archive tool in the launchpad.  I think I've granted access to the role the user is in  - to \applications\archives and everything under it, but I think I'm missing something.  Is that just granting them access to the tool?  Do I need to manually set up a button that goes to the archive?  The button/category doesn't show up on the user's launchpad.  Using 8.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default button for the Archive application on the Launchpad. In fact, the application itself is not intended to run as its own application.

It can be done, however (though it looks a little funny).

## Add a Launchpad button to the Archive

1. In the core database, add an item of template `LaunchPad-Button` (   /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Templates/LaunchPad-Button) to one of the Launchpad button sections below `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons`

   - Note: I chose to duplicate the `RecycleBin` button item
2. Change the **Link** field to `/sitecore/shell/applications/archives/archive`
3. Optionally, change the **Text** and **Icon** fields to indicate what this application does

Return to the LaunchPad and you should see a button for the Archive:
[image: Updated launchpad]